# Adding cardview to relative layout, relative layout to scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am attempting to programatically, when the user presses a button, add a cardview to a scrollview.

However, I realised that I got this error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

I read this article [How can I avoid "IllegalStateException: Scrollview can host only one direct child"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735095/how-can-i-avoid-illegalstateexception-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-chil) and realised I had to create a  linearlayout.

So, I am now adding my cardview to a linearlayout, then adding that linearlayout to the scrollview. However I am still getting issues.

```
Error:

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:233)
                at com.app.appname.create.CreateCardViewProgrammatical


    ----------


    ----------


    ly(create.java:97)
                at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.create$1.onClick(create.java:52)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

line 97: `scrollView.addView(linearLayout);`
line 52                 `CreateCardViewProgrammatically();`
```

create.java

```
  public class create extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    Context context;
    CardView cardview;
    LayoutParams layoutparams;
    TextView textview;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    ScrollView scrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);

        scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CreateCardViewProgrammatically();

            }
        });
    }

    public void CreateCardViewProgrammatically(){

        cardview = new CardView(context);

        layoutparams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

        cardview.setRadius(15);

        cardview.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);

        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(30);

        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(6);

        textview = new TextView(context);

        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

        textview.setText("CardView Programmatically");

        textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);

        textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        textview.setPadding(25,25,25,25);

        textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        cardview.addView(textview);

        linearLayout.addView(cardview);

        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    }

}
```

xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:minHeight="170dp"
        tools:context=".create"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
        >




        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="438dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                tools:context="com.android_examples.cardviewprogrammatically_android_examplescom.MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout1">


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click here to Create CardView programmatically on Button click"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>








        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorCreate"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorBackground"/>



        <View
            android:id="@+id/subheading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:background="@color/colorText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:background="@color/colorText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/done_label"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/aisle_label"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/qty_label"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/item_label"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `scrollView.addView(linearLayout);`

Comment: Ok well that runs now but when I press the FAB to add the cardviews, I don't see anything being added

Comment: @NileshRathod is it because of any margins or the width and height of scrollview