# IllegalStateException for ScrollView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, scrollview, illegalstateexception

I have been getting these crash reports from my app, but I just can't see to recreate the error on my own, no matter what. I made sure all ScrollViews only have 1 child.

Here is my stack trace:

```
at android.widget.ScrollView.addView (ScrollView.java:273)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1425)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1750)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1819)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (BackStackRecord.java:855)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2587)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2377)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2332)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:851)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:794)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed (FragmentActivity.java:181)
  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp (Activity.java:2999)
  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2715)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:3291)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:534)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:374)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5170)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5042)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4416)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4416)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4525)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4582)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4416)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4416)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4719)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:2459)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:2022)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:2013)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:2436)
  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:141)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:325)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:142)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6651)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Here are some potential places where it could be happening:

1. I am using FragmentTransaction (support), to replace a ScrollView view with regular layouts/Fragments, instead of FrameLayout, to have the layouts be scrollable. ScrollView INHERITS FrameLayout however.
2. I am reusing the same dialog throughout multiple activities/fragments, and changing the contents depending on which enum/state is selected.
3. I am allowing configuration changes on dialog boxes.

None of those 3 cause errors for my me on simulators or phones, but it's doing it in the live app. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid "IllegalStateException: Scrollview can host only one direct child"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735095/how-can-i-avoid-illegalstateexception-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-chil)

Comment: As I mentioned, I did my best to make sure that wasn't the case. I am well aware of the other thread.

Comment: post your layout

Comment: I have a ton of layouts. I don't know where it's coming from.